# Express multiple roles middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I want to have 2 access roles: admin and superadmin.

Superadmin can create, read, update and delete posts.
Admin can read, update posts.

I have the middlewares already:

```
const verifyAdminStatus = (req, res, next) => {
  //pseudocode: if (user === 'admin') next();
}

const verifySuperAdminStatus = (req, res, next) => {
  //pseudocode: if (user === 'superadmin') next();
}
```

For create and delete it works fine:

```
router.post("/api/posts", [verifyToken, verifySuperAdminStatus], createPost); 
router.delete("/api/posts/:id", [verifyToken, verifySuperAdminStatus], deletePost);
```

But for update and read, I can't put both middlewares, because either one of them will not have the access. How can I implement a solution where both admins and superadmins can update and read. Do I need to create a new middleware that checks both?

Comment: You can create a third function, but you can also refactor things a bit. For instance: `const verifyStatus = roles => (req, res, next) => { if (roles.includes(user.role) next(); };` This way you can pass `verifyStatus(['superadmin'])` or `verifyStatus(['admin', 'superadmin'])` as your middleware.

Comment: Or keep a list of the user roles: `if (user === 'superadmin') req.roles.push('superadmin');` then check inside your end handler.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a factory of middleware to have only one middleware that manages the different cases as follow:

```
const authMiddleware = (roles) => {
   return (req,res,next) => {
      roles.forEach(role => {
        if(["admin", "superadmin"].includes(role)) return next();
      })
      return res.status(403).json({
        message: "Forbidden"
      })
   }
   
}

router.post("/api/posts", [verifyToken, authMiddleware(["Admin"])], createPost); 
router.delete("/api/posts/:id", [verifyToken, authMiddleware(["SuperAdmin"]], deletePost); 
router.delete("/api/posts/another-endpoint", [verifyToken, authMiddleware(["SuperAdmin", "Admin"]], deletePost);
```

The last endpoint can be consumed for an Admin or Super Admin role.